# How to make my Linux C program accessible from bash

Tags: c, linux, bash

Say I made and compiled a small program in `C` to count the bytes of a file, called `filebyte`. To run it I would use `./filebyte`

Now I want to make it universal on bash, like for example to run a php file,  I would use `bash` command `php file.php`, same way I would like to run my program, `filebyte filename`.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: when you run a command in bash, then that same command will work in a bash script (ie `./filebyte`). If you don't/can't know where the program is, you just put it in one of the `$PATH` directories, so you can execute it as a command isntead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often create a `bin/` directory in my home directory, for small custom applications.

You then need to add that directory to your PATH, which is a list of colon-separated paths that your shell searches for executables when you type a name on thr command line.

This is usually accomplished by putting this in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the environment variable `PATH` and put the executable in one of the directories listed. You can also put it in a custom directory and then append it to `PATH`. You can check it by executing `printenv PATH`

Comment: thanx. I choose Reinharts answere because it fits my need exactly, but upvoted yours too. incase anyone want to know more about `environment variable PATH` [see here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it for your current active shell alone, do

```
export PATH=$PATH:</path/to/file>
```

For permanently making the file available add the above line to `~/.bashrc`

Why add it in `PATH` variable, `man bash` says why,

```
   PATH   The search path for commands.  It is a colon-separated list of 
          directories in which the shell looks for commands (see COMMAND 
          EXECUTION below).  A zero-length (null) directory  name  in the 
          value of PATH indicates the current directory.  A null directory 
          name may appear as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or 
          trailing colon.  The default path is system-dependent, and is set 
          by the administrator who installs bash.  A common value is 
          ''/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/bin''.
```